# How to push integer on Stack in BCEL

Tags: java, bytecode, bcel

I am facing a problem in context of **pushing a integer on stack in BCEL**.
I have a method **_square** of someClass i.e. "**mathClass**"

```
    ilist = new InstructionList();
    ilist.append(InstructionConstants.ALOAD_0);
    ilist.append(new GETFIELD(findex));
   //I am trying to push some value using createLoad but it is not working 

     ilist.append(InstructionConstants.ALOAD_1);
    ilist.append(ifact.createInvoke("mathClass", _square, Type.INT,
       new Type[] { Type.INT }, Constants.INVOKEVIRTUAL));
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
new InstructionList.append(new PUSH(constantPool,23));
```

the push method use to push primitive type data on stack.